# Switch to back camera in iOS application using LFLiveKit

Tags: ios, xamarin, rtmp

I am using [LFLiveKit](https://github.com/rhedgpeth/Xamarin-LFLiveKit) for making a streaming app in Xamarin over RTMP. LFLiveKit has default camera settings set to front camera. I want to make default to rear camera or allow switching of the camera. Not able to figure out how to do it, can someone help if they have earlier worked on LFLiveKit.

Comment: How in the world did you get LFLiveKit to compile? I can't get past the linking errors. Very frustrating.

Comment: Hi @Madhur could you help us with code that you have used for streaming?

Comment: Hi @prashant-gaikwad sadly I do not have access to it. What I can remember is I uncommented the code block starting at line 303 in this link https://github.com/rhedgpeth/Xamarin-LFLiveKit/blob/master/src/LFLiveKit/ApiDefinition.cs and set that to my desired position to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was diving into the Documentation and the Source Code, however I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/rhedgpeth/Xamarin-LFLiveKit/blob/master/src/LFLiveKit/ApiDefinition.cs):

```
// @property (assign, nonatomic) AVCaptureDevicePosition captureDevicePosition;
//[Export("captureDevicePosition", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
//AVCaptureDevicePosition CaptureDevicePosition { get; set; }
```

Which means that, in this package, the captureDevicePosition is commented, so there is no way to change that. You could try and talk to the developers, or open an issue to see if they can do anything about it.

Comment: Hey Bruno, I was able to uncomment **CaptureDevicePosition** and rebuild LFLiveKit project. This made the property accessible in main iOS Application and I was able to switch to back camera. You just saved my day!!

Comment: Oh, nice! Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as correct @MadhurMaurya

Comment: Done @bruno-caceiro